# How do I write an XML file using javascript only?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, web

For the last 3 weeks I've been working on a factory's tool crib, I'm here because they don't have any software to control their inventory and my boss is worried if he buys a software or implements a new system some of his oldest employees will not be able to use it.

I already have a working interface I made using HTML, JavaScript and css; problem is I can't install any server, or have it connected to no database because of the corporation's policies, so I'm having trouble making either a database that I can connect using ONLY MS-Access, HTML and JavaScript or replace MS-Access with XML. I really don't have many options left but to either break the rules and install a server anyways (which can get me into trouble), or get creative and solve this using what I already have.

I thought about dropping all I've done until now and start from scratch using visual studio or other environment, but time is not in my favor, actually I need this to be fixed and pronto.

I already tried some scripts I've found elsewhere but they don't seem to do anything for me, so up until now all I have that works is my interface.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Those corporate policies ban specific things for specific reasons or they're just vague guidelines to prevent work from being done? Is XML a goal itself or it's a tool to accomplish something? (Whatever, when they finally go out of business I suppose they'll blame the economy.)

Comment: @stckrboy: But that won't help other computers.

Comment: Those policies prevent me from installing a server and by consequence any kind of database, because they don't want any vulnerability in their intranet. No, XML is not a goal, is a tool I thought could help me create a Data Base without using a server. I have Microsoft Acces at my dispose but since I have no server I find it very difficult to actually use it.

Comment: @SLaks - you're correct, I thought functionality was there when it was not (thinking local intranet). Removed my comment

Comment: I tried this code but it doesn't create an XML file as I thought it would
function xmlForMe(){
 var v = new  XMLWriter();
 v.writeStartDocument(true);
 v.writeElementString('test','Hello World');
 v.writeAttributeString('foo','bar');
 v.writeEndDocument();
 console.log( v.flush() );
}

Comment: If this question really is about writing an XML file then you should remove the [tag:ms-access] tag.

Comment: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/ maybe this ?

Comment: @user3624321: XML won't help you at all.  Without a server, you have no way to store data that can be read by multiple users.

Comment: @SLaks I don't need it to be read by multiple users. I just need it to work in just one pc.

Comment: Then you can just use localStorage; you don't need XML.  Beware that it will only be stored in that browser and only until you clear data.

Comment: Apart from Access, there are many database engines that do not have client-server architecture (if that's the issue): SQLite, BerkeleyDB... And there're endless programming languages that provide database libraries and do not run on a dedicated server. After all, computers could already do stuff before networking was invented. I'm sorry but this question is terribly broad and not a good fit for Stack Overflow.